# commonsMultipartFile trouble

Tags: grails, file-upload, groovy

Hi I have am trying to implement a file upload in my application where the file uploaded is parsed and an entry is created in the database using that information.

```
 def save = {

        def file = request.getFile("file");
        def filename = file.getOriginalFilename();
        def type = filename.split('\\.');

        if(!file.isEmpty()){
            if(type[1] == "properties"){

                redirect(action:"parsePropertyFile", params:params);
            }
        }
 }

def parsePropertyFile = {

      println "\n"
      println params.file;
      println "\n";

      def f = params.file;
      println f;

      def filename = f.getOriginalFilename();
      println filename;
}
```

when I print out `f` this is output:

```
org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile@29d32df9
```

but when I try to call `getOriginalFilename()` on `f` I get the following error:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: 
java.lang.String.getOriginalFilename() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
```

I also printed out `file` from the save function and the output of that is also:

```
org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile@29d32df9
```

so why am I getting the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of redirecting, can you just call your another function? Redirect will issue an http redirect with the file as param with no need.

```
if(type[1] == "properties") {
  parsePropertyFile(file)
}
```

And then:

```
private def parsePropertyFile(def file) {
  String filename = file.getOriginalFilename();
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `parsePropertyFile` action you aren't getting a File object, you're getting the String from `params`.  Just like in your `save` action, you need to do

```
def f = request.getFile('file')
println f.getOriginalFilename()
```